Looking for a Globe and Mail editorial cartoon about the return of Hong Kong to China
Sometime in 1997, or shortly after, the Globe and Mail ran an editorial cartoon commenting on the return of Hong Kong to China. The setting was a drab boardroom, with several drab functionaries sitting around the table — on the table is what looks like a very colourful amusement park, and one of the men is saying, "Now that we've got it, what do we do with it?".
Does anyone remember the name of the artist, or even the exact date?
Thanks!

One of the first things I wanted to be growing up was a political cartoonist (sadly, no drawing skill at all). If your timing was right, it looks like the cartoonist was likely a gent named Brian Gable

It looks like Trinity University has an archive of 4,000 of his cartoons, but as of 2 years ago was asking for volunteer help organizing it all. I doubt that work is done.
